# MSSQL join tables w bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, pivot, sqlfiddle

I have three tables : 
1) UserTable

```
UserId UserName 
  1      Mike
  2      John
  3      Jennifer
```

2) FormName

```
fID   fName
 1     edit
 2     cafe
 3     backoffice
```

3)User to form

```
fId  UserId   Allowed(bit)
 1     1         0
 2     1         1
 3     1         1
 2     2         1 
 3     2         0
```

The first table is the user table with user informations.
The second table is the form table where it stores form names of application
The third table is user level table where it says which user is allowed to open which form .

I want to create sql query where I can see all information in a single table like :

```
UserId USerName   Edit  Cafe BackOffice
  1      mike      0     1      1  
  2      john      1     1      0
```

I think it is possbile with SQL Fiddle and Pivot but I am having hard time to figure the right code out .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT function, but you have to `cast` the `allowed` column to something other than a `bit` datatype. For example, the below casts it to an `int`:

```
select userid, username,
  coalesce(Edit, 0) Edit, 
  coalesce(Cafe, 0) Cafe, 
  coalesce(BackOffice, 0)  BackOffice
from
(
  select u.userid, 
    u.username, 
    f.fname, 
    cast(allowed as int) allowed
  from usertable u
  inner join user_form uf
    on u.userid = uf.userid
  inner join formname f
    on uf.fid = f.fid
) d
pivot
(
  max(allowed)
  for fname in (Edit, Cafe, BackOffice)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83835/10)